# How do I tell Pig what a PyObject is?

Tags: python, jython, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I have a Pig script that uses a Python UDF. It worked two days ago, but then someone updated Apache Pig to version 0.11.0-cdh4.3.0.  Since then I get this error:

```
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/python/core/PyObject
```

I have tried having the HADOOP_CLASSPATH, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300509/how-do-you-use-python-udfs-with-pig-in-elastic-mapreduce), updated with the Jython jar, but that does not change anything. I did log out and back in, but the same error happens. All of the scripts running Java UDFs work fine. I also tried registering the jython.jar in my script. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300509/how-do-you-use-python-udfs-with-pig-in-elastic-mapreduce .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding $PIG_HOME/lib/jython.jar to your $PIG_CLASSPATH environment variable.